# need the menuconfig database in EXCEL?

Tags: linux, database

Is there a way to obtain the help text, "selected by," "selects," and other fields for every configuration option, just like those available in the `menuconfig`, without running `menuconfig`? Perhaps in an Excel file or some other kind of database?

Precise format:  Config_name, help text, selects, selected by(processed and given in menuconfig), depends on(processed in menuconfig)

Answer (score 1):

The help text for each section of the kernel is in a corresponding `Kconfig` file in the kernel source tree. You can collect the entire text with a series of commands like this

```
# Download a version of the kernel source (Debian)
mkdir src
cd src
apt-get source linux

# Dump the contents of all Kconfig files
find -type f -name Kconfig -exec cat {} + | "${PAGER:-less}"
```

Without a more precise output format it's impossible to know what level of detail you require. For example, the menu configuration system is hierarchical but spreadsheet sheets are flat.

Comment: Precise format: Config_name, help text, selects, selected by(processed and given in menuconfig), depends on(processed in menuconfig), I need the hierarchial information that menuconfig provides in flat sheet

Comment: any additions to finding the depends on and selected by columns?